# htacess rewrite for AltoRouter to include redirect to https

Tags: php, .htaccess, altorouter

I'm using Altorouter which requires the following in htacess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

This is working just fine but I also need to redirect http to https.  I found examples online but all my efforts to combine the two have failed.  How would I combine the top snippet with this?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```